# unable to create virtual network data gateway on power BI - premium per user reserved pp3 sku is not supported

Tags: powerbi

Unable to create a virtual network data gateway on powerBI. unsure as to what the root cause is, but this is what I can see on the screen, can anyone please clarify the correct licence type required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Unable-to-create-a-virtual-network-data-gateway-PP3-sku-is-not/m-p/3795400

I think it's a licensing issue